# How to change the CSS value (color tag) using a JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the value of the color or background-color of a stylesheet using a JavaScript function. For example, changing background-color from blue to red.

If some could lead me to the right direction, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the values in stylesheet through javascript.

Instead you can override css style using javascript.

Ex.

HTML

```
<div id="test">This is a div</div>
```

CSS

```
#test {background-color: red};
```

Javascript

```
var el = document.getElementById("test");
el.style.background = 'green';
```

// This will override CSS

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but the concept is
select the element to which you want to apply css.apply css by using following method:
`document.getElementById("theId").css("Property","value");`
or
`document.getElementById("theId").style.backgroundColor = 'somecolor';`

> Example:
>   https://code.sololearn.com/WRAhi76nv7Qb/#html